# Bootstrap prevents form from submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have been struggling to figure our what is going on here.

So, I have super basic form. But bootstrap prevents it from submission. Neither

`<button value="submit" type="submit">` 
nor 
`<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>` works. Once I disable bootstrap, form submits.

Seems to be a wierd e.preventDefault triggering. But why? I don't get it...

My form:

```
<div class="well page active" id="personalInfo" data-toggle="tab">
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="test/save">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="surname" class="col-md-2 control-label">surname</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" name="surname" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <button value="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="c9e458bf-6565-4b8d-bba7-6516af8e1be9">
</form>
</div>
```

This is stacktrace and what prevents it:
[image: debug]

Comment: Create a demo in sandbox site like jsfiddle.net or other similar site that reproduces problem. Image shows tab related code but no tabs shown in question html

Comment: Please add your action="test/save" code that your form is calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of the

```
data-toggle="tab"
```

on the parent div. Bootstrap is tying the entire content of the div to that click event. If you intend to have the clickable tab also contain the form you will want to manually handle the tab events.

Ex.

Script:

```
$('#personalInfo a').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault()
   $(this).tab('show')
});
```

Html:

```
<div class="well page active" id="personalInfo">
<a href='#'>Tab</a>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="test/save">
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="surname" class="col-md-2 control-label">surname</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" name="surname" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <button value="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="c9e458bf-6565-4b8d-bba7-6516af8e1be9">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. Although it's silly that forms inside standard tab are prevented from submission.